# SpatialPolygonsDataFrame chloroplethr not writing to KML for GoogleMaps using R

Tags: polygon, r, google-maps, kml, maptools

I'm trying to do a simple chloropleth map for postal codes. I have the orginal kml exported [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e5s8aq0lhs7pfn2/CP_04Camp_v2.kml?dl=0).

When importing into R, i'm doing:

```
library(rgdal)
library(rworldmap)
library(plotKML)
library(maptools)

foo <- readOGR("CP_04Camp_v2.kml")
```

This yields a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame :

```
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 176 
extent      : -92.46879, -89.38602, 17.81287, 20.455  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs 
variables   : 2
names       : Name, Description 
min values  :     ,             
max values  :     ,
```

First, I tried to add a column in the foo@data with the color attribute, but I keep having a hard time exporting the kml to use in Google Maps.

I have been trying:

```
> plotKML::kml(obj = foo, "test.kml")
KML file opened for writing...
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  Proj4string does not contain \+datum= parameter.
 Consider converting to the referent CRS +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 manually.
```

Or using maptools:

```
> kmlPolygons(obj = foo, kmlfile = "test.kml")
Warning message:
In rep(col, length.out = length(obj)) :
  'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL
```

I get the same error messages even if I don't even "touch" the imported object. What am I missing?

session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] maptools_0.8-41 plotKML_0.5-6   rworldmap_1.3-6 needs_0.0.3     rgdal_1.2-5     sp_1.2-4        xlsx_0.5.7     
 [8] xlsxjars_0.6.1  rJava_0.9-8     readxl_0.1.1    ggmap_2.6.1     RODBC_1.3-14    memisc_0.99.7-1 MASS_7.3-45    
[15] lattice_0.20-34 magrittr_1.5    ggplot2_2.2.1   inegiR_1.2.0    tse.utils_0.1.0 tse.sql_0.1.0   stringr_1.1.0  
[22] dplyr_0.5.0     foreign_0.8-67 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] nlme_3.1-128        pixmap_0.4-11       pbkrtest_0.4-6      xts_0.9-7           devtools_1.12.0    
 [6] RColorBrewer_1.1-2  backports_1.0.4     tools_3.3.2         R6_2.2.0            rpart_4.1-10       
[11] Hmisc_4.0-2         DBI_0.5-1           lazyeval_0.2.0      mgcv_1.8-15         colorspace_1.2-7   
[16] nnet_7.3-12         raster_2.5-8        withr_1.0.2         gridExtra_2.2.1     quantreg_5.29      
[21] htmlTable_1.8       gstat_1.1-4         SparseM_1.74        checkmate_1.8.2     scales_0.4.1       
[26] classInt_0.1-23     digest_0.6.10       minqa_1.2.4         colorRamps_2.3      RSAGA_0.94-5       
[31] dismo_1.1-4         htmltools_0.3.5     base64enc_0.1-3     jpeg_0.1-8          lme4_1.1-12        
[36] plotrix_3.6-4       maps_3.1.1          FNN_1.1             zoo_1.7-13          jsonlite_1.2       
[41] acepack_1.4.1       car_2.1-4           Formula_1.2-1       shapefiles_0.7      geosphere_1.5-5    
[46] Matrix_1.2-7.1      Rcpp_0.12.7         munsell_0.4.3       proto_1.0.0         stringi_1.1.2      
[51] plyr_1.8.4          grid_3.3.2          parallel_3.3.2      splines_3.3.2       mapproj_1.2-4      
[56] knitr_1.15.1        rjson_0.2.15        spacetime_1.2-0     reshape2_1.4.2      XML_3.98-1.5       
[61] latticeExtra_0.6-28 data.table_1.10.0   png_0.1-7           spam_1.4-0          nloptr_1.0.4       
[66] aqp_1.10            RgoogleMaps_1.4.1   MatrixModels_0.4-1  gtable_0.2.0        reshape_0.8.6      
[71] assertthat_0.1      e1071_1.6-7         class_7.3-14        survival_2.40-1     tibble_1.2         
[76] intervals_0.15.1    memoise_1.0.0       fields_8.10         cluster_2.0.5
```

Comment: the first one works for me with no errors, but it does try to write to "foo.kml" rather than "test.kml". Use `plotKML::kml(obj = foo, file.name="testp.kml")` to specify the file name. The second one gives me that *warning*, not an error, and produces a complete KML file. Suspect you need to update all the packages and maybe R? What versions are you on? Please edit your Q and show them.

Comment: The warning with `kmlPolygons` is because `col=NULL` - if you specify a colour then it goes away, eg: `kmlPolygons(obj = foo, kmlfile = "test.kml",col="red")`

Comment: @Spacedman I added session info

Comment: @Spacedman tried the `col="red"` and it exports but does not load on Google maps (says it has an error)

Comment: see `?add_kml` from `library(googleway)`. Specifically, you can do `google_map(key = apiKey) %>% add_kml()`